# Chrome comes with JQuery in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Does jQuery comes with chrome by default? I opened a blank chrome window in console when i type $ and hit enter i got

```
ƒ $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }
```

And I also able to get the element by putting a selector

```
$('body')
```

Does jQuery or $ comes with chrome by default?

Comment: Maybe it is injected by some chrome extension?

Comment: what do you mean blank chome window?

Comment: No, it isn't by default, see [chrome devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#queryselector)